# How to monitor the cloud function error rate with Google Cloud Monitoring?

Tags: google-cloud-functions, monitoring, google-cloud-monitoring

I'd like to get an alert when a cloud function returns non-OK status codes for more than 90% of executions over 30 minutes.

The series I'm filtering is  `cloudfunctions.googleapis.com/function/execution_count`. Out of all records, I want to count those that satisfy `metric.status != 'ok'`. If 90% of all records over the last 30min satisfy this condition, I want to raise an alert.

I had a look at Google Cloud's Monitoring Query Language documentation and found this part about ratios: https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/mql/examples#qlx-ratio-ratio

Here's how I wrote my condition:

```
fetch cloud_function
| metric 'cloudfunctions.googleapis.com/function/execution_count'
| { filter metric.status != 'ok'
  ; ident }
| group_by [resource.function_name]
| ratio
| window 30m
| condition ratio >= 0.9 '1'
```

It seems to work, and the graphs indicate correct values. However, it seems that as soon as a function returns an error code, the alert is raised even if there are other successful executions along compensating for the problem.

For example, here's the graph of the metrics at the time an alert was raised, which I got in Monitoring > Alerting > (click on the last alert in the events section)
[image: graph at the time of the incident]

*The function reported in the alert is `processPurchase`*

Is there something I'm missing that could cause the problem? Looking at the graphs, it seems the alert should not trigger. Yet, I have events and notifications about the alert. It resolves a few minutes later.

Comment: you need to specify alignment period, `window 30m` is not enough. Try looking into [`every`](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/mql/reference#every-tabop) and [alignment period in alerts](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/concepts-indepth#alignment-period).

Comment: you MIGHT need both `align` and `every`, but i cannot remember it right now .. Feel free to self-answer the question, if you can figure it out.

Answer (score 3):

I don’t think `ratio`  could be the best option for you, due to `ratio`   computes the ratio of value columns of two aligned input tables.

I think you could try with the following code:

```
fetch cloud_function
| metric 'cloudfunctions.googleapis.com/function/execution_count'
| align rate(30m)
| every 30m
| group_by [metric.status],
    [value_execution_count_percentile: percentile(value.execution_count, 90)]
```

As you can see I’m using the same metric `cloudfunctions.googleapis.com/function/execution_count`
But using a Period of 30 min, and a percentage of 90% instead of the condition ratio.

#### Edit1

I have create a simple Cloud Function to generate random errors,

```
import random
def hello_world(request):
    request_json = request.get_json()
    x = random.randint(1,2)
    if x%2 ==0:
        raise NameError("my error x.x")
    else:
        return f'Hello World!'
```

and then I used the metric you posted as base to generate my metric:

```
fetch cloud_function
| metric 'cloudfunctions.googleapis.com/function/execution_count'
| { t_0:
      filter metric.status != 'ok'
      | align delta()
      | group_by [resource.function_name],
          [value_execution_count_aggregate: aggregate(value.execution_count)]
  ; t_1:
      ident
      | align delta()
      | group_by [resource.function_name],
          [value_execution_count_aggregate: aggregate(value.execution_count)] }
| ratio
| window 5m
| condition ratio >= 0.5 '1'
```

[image]

I only moved the ratio to `ratio >= 0.5 '1'` instead of 0.9 and reduced the window to 5m in order to not spend all the day getting the data.

But in my Alert Configuration I used:
Condition triggers if All time series violate
Edit threshold by using the condition operator in the query editor = 5

[image]

With this configuration I’m receiving the alert only when the conditions meet, and not as soon as a function returns an error code.

Comment: The `every 30m` part seems to give me the same figure for 30mins, it looks like data is not aggregated over the last 30minutes but a data point is generated every 30mins instead. Isn't there a way to sum the function execution counts over the last 30mins every minute? (1-31, 2-32, 3-33,...)

Comment: @ThomasP. I have edited my original answer.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I still get alerts emitted every time a function crashes or returns an error. Perhaps aggregation is broken?

Comment: Maybe it is something in your trigger condition, in my case if I configure it every 30 min, the alert is triggered only at the minute 30, not every time a function crashes or returns an error. Or as you mentioned, maybe the aggregation is not working with your current configuration of the metric.

Comment: I found `filter_ratio_by`, which seems tailored for this need, maybe that will work? https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/mql/examples#qlx-filter-ratio

Comment: That didn't do the trick, it seems the root cause is that I have sparse run points. So if one failure occurs and the function is not run after that for a while, the failure point has a higher coefficient for the computation of the metric (?). Something's definitely broken with my data points alignment, I tried to switch to `align delta_gauge()`, hopefully that will fix it